A weight formula for subgraphs of $K_n$ and log-concavity of nested binomial coefficients
Nested binomials Let $t,d$ be positive integers and $n$ a parameter. The degree $td$ rational polynomial
$p_{t,d}(n)={{ n \choose t} \choose d}$ obviously takes integral values for integral $n$ (not at all obvious from the expanded polynomial). It follows that it has a unique representation as a polynomial in binomial base ${n \choose k}$
$p_{t,d}(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{td} A_{t,d,k}{n \choose k}$,
where by a result of Polya, $A_{t,d,k}$ are integers. For examples, we have
${{n \choose 2} \choose 2}=\frac{n}{4}-\frac{n^2}{8}-\frac{n^3}{4}+\frac{n^4}{8}=3 {n \choose 3} + 3{n \choose 4}$
${{n \choose 2} \choose 3}={n \choose 3}+16{n \choose 4}+30{n \choose 5}+15{n\choose 6}$
${{n \choose 2} \choose 4}=\frac{n}{8}-\frac{n^2}{96}-\frac{19n^3}{96}+\frac{3n^4}{128}+\frac{n^5}{12}-\frac{n^6}{64}-\frac{n^7}{96}+\frac{n^8}{384}$
$=15{n \choose 4}+135{n \choose 5}+330{n \choose 6}+ 315 { n \choose 7}+105{n \choose 8}.$
It appears that the integral nested coefficients $A_{t,d,k}$ are unimodal and in fact log-concave. Numerical computations suggest this is always true. Is this always true ?
It seems further that if we let
$f_{t,d}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{td} A_{t,d,k}x^{td-k}$
then for $t$ even $f_{t,d}(x)$ are real rooted.
In all cases, $h_{t,d}(x):=f_{t,d}(x-1)$ is always log-concave and palimdormic eg
$h_{2,4}(x)=15x^4+75x^3+15x^2$.
A similar result seems to hold also for all
higher level nested binomial coefficients eg for level three,
${{{n \choose t} \choose d_1} \choose d_2}= \sum_{k=1}^{td_1d_2}A_{t,d_1,d_2,k} {n \choose k}.$
Transforming to binomial base It is known (OEIS A19538) that $x^n=\sum_{k=1}^n T(k,n){n \choose k}$ where
$T(k,n)=k! S(n,k)$, and $S(n,k)$ is Stirling numbers of the second kind so that we have explicit formula for  conversion to binomial base :
$\sum_{j=1}^na_jx^j=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k {x \choose k}$ where $b_k=\sum_{j=k}^n a_jT(k,j).$
$T(k,n)$ are positive, integral , and seemingly log-concave along columns and the obvious polynomials formed for each column has real and distinct roots which interlace as columns varies. A segment of $T$ looks like
$T=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 & 1& 1&1 & 1 & \ldots \cr 0 & 2 & 6 & 14 & 30 & 62 & \ldots \cr 0 & 0 & 6 & 36 & 150 & 540 & \ldots \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 & 240 &1560 & \ldots \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 120 & 1800 & \dots \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 720 & \ldots \cr \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \dots \end{pmatrix}$
The log-concavity of $A_{t,d,k}$ probably just follows from those of $T(k,n)$.
Geometric meaning of the coefficients We are led to consider the nested binomials from a weight formula for enumerating subgraphs of $K_n$. Let $K_n$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices, a subgraph $H$ is just a subset of the edges (so this ignore and excludes isolated points). We recently found a mass or weight formula for enumerating all such subgraphs. Each subgraph has an induced number of vertices $k=k(H)$ (eg. $k=3$ for triangle and $k=6$ for three disjoint edges). The weight formula for subgraphs of $K_n$ is
$ \sum_{H < K_n} {n \choose k} \frac{k!}{|Aut_k(H)|}=2^{n \choose 2},$
where $Aut_k(H)$ is the automorphism group of $H$ as a subgroups of $S_k$ of permutation of the induced vertices. This has a refinement if sum over subgraphs with a fixed number $d$ of edges. (Is this something well known ?)
$ \sum_{H < K_n, |H|=d} {n \choose k} \frac{k!}{|Aut_k(H)|}={{n \choose 2} \choose d}.$
If we now let $a_{2,d,k}$ be the sum over all $H<K_n$ on $d$ edges with the number of induced vertices $k(H)=k$ of the weights,
$(1) \;\;\; a_{2,d,k}:=\sum_{H<K_n,|H|=d,k(H)=k} \frac{k!}{|Aut_s(H)|},$
we will have
$(2) \;\; \sum_{k=1}^{2d} a_{2,d,k}{n \choose k}={{ n \choose 2} \choose d}.$
The upper limit $2d$ is to allow the maximal possible number of induced number of vertices on a union of $d$ disjoint edges but it still holds if $n<2d$ if we follow the usual convention that ${n \choose k}=0$ if $k<n$.
The weight formula (2) give a constraint on our geometric data $a_{2,d,k}$ but we then realize the constraint determine the data uniquely viewing ${{n \choose 2 }  \choose d}$ as a polynomial in $n$ and expressing it in its unique binomial base. We must now have
$a_{2,d,k}=A_{2,d,k}$
so that can now rewrite (1) as
$\sum_{H<K_n,|H|=d,k(H)=k} \frac{k!}{|Aut_s(H)|}=A_{t,d,k},$
and viewed it as a refined weight formula since the RHS can be defined independently. Every thing still holds if we replace $2$ by $t$
$ \sum_{H < K_n, |H|=d} {n \choose k} \frac{k!}{|Aut_k(H)|}={{n \choose t} \choose d},$
where $H$ now is over isomorphism class of t-uniform hyper-subgraphs of $K_n$. The real rootedness of examples we computed for $f_{t,d}(x)$ and the palindromic nature of $h_{t,d}(x)$ lead us to guess it might always holds.
This seem very similar to a recently resolved difficult conjecture but may be this case (counting different things) is easier since it can de defined without the geometry, just based on properties of the Stirling numbers $T(k,n)$ ?
The weight formula is very useful when enumerating subgraphs especially uniform hyper-subgraphs of $K_n$, as a check that the enumeration is correct and complete.
We are lead to it via a Ramsey number functional which counts monochromatic 2-colored hyper-subgraphs.

Possible idea: You can write ${n\choose k}={n^{\underline k}\over k!}$, where $n^{\underline k}=n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)$ denotes the falling factorial. Then $x^{\underline n}=\sum_k\bigl\lbrack{n\atop k}\bigr\rbrack(-1)^{n-k}x^k$ (see for example Equation (6.13) in Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's Concrete Mathematics; here $\bigl\lbrack{n\atop k}\bigr\rbrack$ denotes a Stirling number of the first kind), and you may be able to find formulas for $A_{t,d,k}$ like this.

I assume the explicit formula for conversion to binomial base is known. Added now with more information. You need to invert your formula and use Stirling of the second kind.

It's probably worth noting that the coefficient of $\binom{n}{k}$ in $\binom{\binom{n}{i}}{j}$ is equal to the number of ways to take $j$ sets of size $i$ such that their union is ${1,2,\dots, k}$.   This suggests an approach to proving log-concavity, by constructing an injection between pairs of such coverings of appropriate sizes, but I don't see how to actually make that work.

Yes. If we fixed $i=2$, we can think of a $j$ subset as a subgraph $H$ of $K_n$ on $j$ edges which we can count over isomorphism classes of $H$ but the multiplicities will depend on the number of induced vertices and its automorphism group. For $i>2$, it just count i-uniform hyper-subgraphs. See added section

It follows from (1) that $A_{t,d,k} \ge 0$ not so obvious from the binomial definition.

For $t=2$, ${{ n \choose t} \choose d}$ is the number of ways to choose $d$ edges from $K_n$ Each such choice defines a subgraph $H$ of $K_n$ on $d$ edges and it has a number $k(H)$ of induced vertices. There is such a copy for each ${ n\choose k}$ choices of $k$ vertices of $K_n$. But within a fixed choice of vertices, there are also copies of $H$, under the action of $G=S_k$, the orbit size is exactly $|G/G_H|$ where $G_H$ is the stabilizer subgroup, so the orbit  size is $\frac{k!}{|Aut_s(H)|}$. So we have $\sum_{H < K_n,|H|=d} {n \choose k} \frac{k!}{|Aut_k(H)|}={{ n \choose t} \choose d}$
